# insufficent storage space for apps

Tags: storage

Have a new zenithink C95 tablet.Getting insufficient storage space error when installing apps.Have 16 gig internal flash drive and 16 gig SD card which still have 12 gig and 14 gig still available.Have nearly a page of apps loaded.Going into storage menu there is a 1 gig partition that the apps are loaded into,which is now full.Even though it is advertised as having 16 gigs internal storage for apps ,music,videos etc,you can't get any more than 950mb of apps on it,which is pretty useless for a tablet. EBay supplier of tablet says they are all like this,but will try and contact zenithink for maybe a firmware update.
Any ideas on sorting this out?
Thanks steve

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't sound like you can do anything yourself (short of rooting the device, and installing a different ROM version).

I don't think as an Android user, you will be able to change how this (poor) design was implemented without changing the OS.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any ideas regarding your hardware configuration problem. But to solve your problem you can move your apps to SD card using stock android move to SD card feature or try third party apps such as Link2SD available on play store